# change bgcolor in html table depending on client input

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have seen a number of similar questions but none that appear to answer what I am trying to do.

In a form on page 1 the following three pieces of information will be entered for a measurement, (1)upper limit, (2)lower limit and (3)measured value.

The user will then click on a button taking them to page 2 where the entered information will be uploaded to a mysql data base, this all works well. On page 2 the entered information will be displayed confirming what has been uploaded to the data base. This information is displayed in a html table.

I wish to change the bgcolor of the cell where the measured value is displayed to RED if not a value that is between (1) upper limit or (2) lower limit .

The three pieces of information entered by the user can and will change every time.

Can this be done simply ?

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: Where do you want to set the color? In the PHP code generating the 2nd page, in the javascript in that page, or in the CSS file? Without showing the code, there's no way we can even start to answer.

Comment: Have not got any code as do not know how to do what I want. Using php to pass variable for the inputs from page 1 to page 2.

Comment: would like to set on page 2 using php variables from page 1 something like if v1 is greater than v2 and v1 less than v3 then bgcolor is x else bgcolor is y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already displaying the information on 2nd page in `HTML table` . Assuming the variables are `$upper_limit`, `$lower_limit` and `$measured`, you can add a check and use bgcolor as a variable as below:

```
<?php
$bg = ($measured<$lower_limit || $measured>$upper_limit) ? 'bgcolor="red"' : '';
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td <?php echo $bg;?>>
             <?php echo $measured; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below link can help you, listen for input value change and use jquery to set the appropriate BG. https://jsfiddle.net/fkacm5rz/5/

```
var input = document.querySelector('#number');
```

var messages = document.querySelector('#text');

```
input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    messages.textContent += 'input changed to: ' + input.value ;
    if(input.value === '1') {
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById("text").style.color = "green";
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
    <input id="number" type="input">

    <div id="text">update </div>
```

Comment: @ChinaTonka does this helps?